# Merge two text input files, each line of the files one after the other. See example

Tags: java-8, stream, java-stream

I was trying to solve a problem using java 8 that I have already solved using a simple for loop. However I have no idea how to do this.
The Problem is :

```
File1 : 
1,sdfasfsf
2,sdfhfghrt
3,hdfxcgyjs

File2 : 
10,xhgdfgxgf
11,hcvcnhfjh
12,sdfgasasdfa
13,ghdhtfhdsdf
```

Output should be like

```
1,sdfasfsf
10,xhgdfgxgf
2,sdfhfghrt
11,hcvcnhfjh
3,hdfxcgyjs
12,sdfgasasdfa
13,ghdhtfhdsdf
```

I already have this basically working,

The core logic is :

```
List<String> left  = readFile(lhs);
List<String> right = readFile(rhs);
int leftSize = left.size();
int rightSize = right.size();
int size =  leftSize > rightSize? leftSize : right.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(i < leftSize) {
        merged.add(left.get(i));
    }
    if(i < rightSize) {
        merged.add(right.get(i));
    }
}
```

- [MergeInputs.java](https://github.com/comdotlinux/java-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/linux/test/merge/list/MergeInputs.java)
- [UnitTest](https://github.com/comdotlinux/java-exercises/blob/master/src/test/java/com/linux/test/merge/list/MergeInputsTest.java)
- Input files are in src/test/resources/com/linux/test/merge/list of the same repo (only allowed to post two links)

However, I boasted I could do this easily using streams and now I am not sure if this can even be done.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: Not posting as answer since it doesn't use streams but this is easy and less error prone with apache commons iterator utilities: `List<String> merged = IteratorUtils.toList(IteratorUtils.zippingIterator(left.iterator(), right.iterator()));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simplify your operation to have less conditionals per element:

```
int leftSize = left.size(), rightSize = right.size(), min = Math.min(leftSize, rightSize);
List<String> merged = new ArrayList<>(leftSize+rightSize);
for(int i = 0; i < min; i++) {
    merged.add(left.get(i));
    merged.add(right.get(i));
}
if(leftSize!=rightSize) {
    merged.addAll(
        (leftSize<rightSize? right: left).subList(min, Math.max(leftSize, rightSize)));
}
```

Then, you *may* replace the first part by a stream operation:

```
int leftSize = left.size(), rightSize = right.size(), min = Math.min(leftSize, rightSize);

List<String> merged=IntStream.range(0, min)
        .mapToObj(i -> Stream.of(left.get(i), right.get(i)))
        .flatMap(Function.identity())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
if(leftSize!=rightSize) {
    merged.addAll(
        (leftSize<rightSize? right: left).subList(min, Math.max(leftSize, rightSize)));
}
```

But it isn’t really simpler than the loop variant. The loop variant may be even more efficient due to its presized list.

Incorporating both operation into one stream operation would be even more complicated (and probably even less efficient).

Comment: Thanks, Sounds good. I will look into the Function.identity() and flatmap more :) Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

the code logic should be like as this:

```
int leftSize = left.size();
int rightSize = right.size();
int minSize = Math.min(leftSize,rightSize);

for (int i = 0; i < minSize; i++) {
    merged.add(left.get(i));
    merged.add(right.get(i));
}

// adding remaining elements
merged.addAll(
        minSize < leftSize ? left.subList(minSize, leftSize)
                           : right.subList(minSize, rightSize)
);
```

Another option is using toggle mode through `Iterator`, for example:

```
toggle(left, right).forEachRemaining(merged::add);

//OR using stream instead
List<String> merged = Stream.generate(toggle(left, right)::next)
                            .limit(left.size() + right.size())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the `toggle` method as below:

```
<T> Iterator<? extends T> toggle(List<T> left, List<T> right) {
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private final int RIGHT = 1;
        private final int LEFT = 0;
        int cursor = -1;
        Iterator<T>[] pair = arrayOf(left.iterator(), right.iterator());

        @SafeVarargs
        private final Iterator<T>[] arrayOf(Iterator<T>... iterators) {
            return iterators;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            for (Iterator<T> each : pair) {
                if (each.hasNext()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            return pair[cursor = next(cursor)].next();
        }

        private int next(int cursor) {
            cursor=pair[LEFT].hasNext()?pair[RIGHT].hasNext()?cursor: RIGHT:LEFT;
            return (cursor + 1) % pair.length;
        }
    };
}
```